# PHP Mongo count not working with multiple fields

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following PHP function, which inserts the JSON object into mongodb if the 'revision_no' field doesn't match, and updates both fields if it does match.

```
function saveJson($data){
    $mongo = new Mongo();
    $db = $mongo->selectDB("technical");
    $db->createCollection("ge",false);
    $technical = $db->selectCollection("ge");
    $json = json_decode($data['data']);
    $count = $technical->count(array('job_id' => $data['job_id'], 'revision_no' => $data['revision_no']));
    echo $count;
    if($count > 0){
        //With just job_id, it returns the correct count
        //$technical->update(array('job_id' => $data['job_id']), $json);
        $technical->update(array('job_id' => $data['job_id'], 'revision_no' => $data['revision_no']), $json);
    }else{
        $technical->insert($json);
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't seem to get the count to work with the combination of job_id & revision_no; but it does work with just the job_id. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: this might be a typo between code and question but you searching by `revision_no` not `revision_id`

Comment: Your code seems fine, so definitely there is typo. Check out for that if any or share complete code from where passing variables.

Comment: This shouldn't work but if you used `find(array('job_id' => $data['job_id'], 'revision_no' => $data['revision_no']))->cont()` instead what happens?

Comment: also, you might use update with upsert flag instead of conditional inserting/updating: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-operations-with-the-upsert-flag

Comment: Made a bit of progress now. revision_no is 0 by default, and mongodb saves this as an integer. I find that if I use this line for the count

      `$count = $technical->count(array('job_id' => $data['job_id'], "revision_no" => (int)$data['revision_no']));`


then it returns correctly. However, now when I increment the revision to 1, the reverse happens; it gets saved as a string and doesn't respond to the count! A bit confusing!

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared an example of the `$data` argument. Based on your last comment, and your answer below, it looks like you're having trouble with types of the `revision_no` field. As a best practice, you should be consistent in the types you use for document fields in your collection. Using a mixture of strings and integers will only cause headaches, since MongoDB will not consider `"1"` equal to `1` when evaluating your query criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was ussing array syntax when I should have been using object style! So its not $data['revision_no'] but $json->revision_no

```
function saveJson($data){
    $mongo = new Mongo();
    $db = $mongo->selectDB("technical");
    $db->createCollection("ge",false);
    $technical = $db->selectCollection("ge");
    $json = json_decode($data['data']);
    $count = $technical->count(array('job_id' => $data['job_id'], 'revision_no' => $json->revision_no));
    echo $count;
    if($count > 0){
        //With just job_id, it returns the correct count
        //$technical->update(array('job_id' => $data['job_id']), $json);
        $technical->update(array('job_id' => $data['job_id'], 'revision_no' => $json->revision_no), $json);
    }else{
        $technical->insert($json);
    }
}
```